# How to plot shapefile in R

Tags: raster, shapefile, r

I am trying to plot a shapefile on top of a raster using the command `readOGR`. My current code is:

```
    CEZ <- readOGR(".", "Shapefile/CEZ1")
```

This is followed by the error code

> Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,        :
> Cannot open data source

I am unsure what this code means - Is it a problem with the shapefile, the command or the way I have structured the path?

Comment: The first argument `dsn` is the path and the `layer` argument is the name of the shapefile without the .shp extension. You are passing a partial path argument to the layer argument where it should just be "CEZ1". If you need to get to a sub-directory in your wd you can use something like `file.path(getwd(), "Shapefile")` for the dsn argument. The suggestion by @Spacedman removes these complications.

Answer (score 0):

The raster package has a handy wrapper function for reading shapefiles. You should be able to do:

```
library(raster)
CEZ <- shapefile("./Shapefile/CEZ1.shp")
```

if that's where your shapefile really is. You might get a better error message.

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your response. I'm still getting the same error. I've realised that the shape file is a polyline rather than a polygon, do you think this could be the reason why I am getting the error code?

Comment: @fionant97 No this is not the problem, `rgdal::readOGR` and the `raster::shapefile` wrapper will read any valid feature geometry. Are you sure that your data is residing in the "Shapefile" subdirectory of your current working directory? You can check using `list.files(file.path(getwd(), "Shapefile"), "shp$")` if you data is not listed then it is not in the specified directory.

Comment: Hi, I've moved the shapefile and its associated files to be in a folder by itself. It has now come up with the error      `Error in .local(x, ...) : file.exists(extension(x, ".shp")) is not TRUE`  from what I have found on the forum, this is usually because the other files are not in the same folder e.g. .shx and .dbf, however I have made sure mine area... really not sure what's going on!

Comment: (Step1): library(raster) (Step2):Name<-rast('FilePath') (Step3):plot(Name)